# view.findViewById(....) always return null in dialog

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have a dialog where I wish to force the user to fill in a name into an EditText, if it's empty I wish for pressing done to have no effect. However,

```
EditText x = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
```

always returns null. I have tried searching but have only found the solution to add a view to findViewById(...) but I already have that. My guess it that it has to do with me creating my own version of the button.

This is the code for the Dialog.

```
package com.example.dialogruta;


@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "ValidFragment" })
public class RecordDialog extends DialogFragment {


public  Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.record_fragment, null);
    builder.setView(view).setPositiveButton("Save experiment", null); //Creating my own 

    final Dialog d = builder.create();
    d.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {

            Button b = ((AlertDialog) d).getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    EditText x = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
                    if( x!= null && !x.toString().isEmpty()){
                        String xs = x.getText().toString();
                        d.dismiss();
                    }
                    else{
                        //TODO: Stuff
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    return d;
}


}
```

And this is the .xml-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


        <EditText
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:hint="Experiment name" />

        <EditText
    android:id="@+id/notes"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dip"
    android:layout_weight ="1"
    android:lines="5"
    android:minLines="1"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:hint="Notes" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

Change View name

```
final View main_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.record_fragment, null);
builder.setView(main_view).setPositiveButton("Save experiment", null);
```

and use it

```
EditText x = (EditText) main_view.findViewById(R.id.name);
```

because in your `public void onClick(View view) {` onclick has `view` that edit text need to refer `inflated` view. Not onclick view.

**Or**

As like @Raghunandan said change onclick `view` name as `public void onClick(View v) {`

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
public void onClick(View view) {
```

to

```
public void onClick(View v) {
```

You have

```
final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.record_fragment, null);
```

and this

```
public void onClick(View view) {
```

Both `View view`.

What happens here

```
 @Override
 public void onClick(View view) {
 EditText x = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
```

EditText is not a child of button and `view.findViewById` looks for a view in the current view hierarchy. It should look for the view in the inflated layout  `final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.record_fragment, null);`

Comment: Changing a variable's name has no effect.

Comment: @stemadsen did you try it before downvoting? It does coz edittext is not a child of button

Comment: This works, but I think it's better code style to refer to the inflated view with `this.view` instead of coming up with different variable names. In this case it's not too bad, but generally it will be more consistent and transparent if one uses the most logical variable name (like `view`) and sticks to it, then refers to a field variable with the `this.` prefix. Just my opinion.

Comment: @stemadsen renaming will also improve readability and avoid confusion

Comment: PS. My immediate mild aggression was due to the fact that, taken out of context, the advice to simply rename a variable seemed both ineffective and stupid. But of course an explanation can very well defend that solution :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50772/discussion-between-raghunandan-and-stemadsen)

Comment: @stemadsen `this.view` won't work. coz this refers to annonymous inner class which does not a variable called type and its not stupid nor ineffective

Comment: You are absolutely right, I must have misread the code or maybe I'm just tired. In this case we have to rename at least one of the variables.

Answer (score 0):

change local view name in onClick() method.

```
public void onClick(View v)
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable as **private** at the onCreate method beginning and access there.

```
EditText x = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
```

Now you will get the value of x in onClick() method.